# Error solving matrix product using nested for loops

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain matrix product using nested for loop but it throws an error..

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([1,7,8],[2,7,9],[4,8,8]])
B = np.array([[3,5,6]])

for i in range(len(A)):
   for j in range(len(B[0])):
       for k in range(len(A)):
           C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j]
print C
```

Comment: What error? Please show your traceback.

Comment: Your square brackets for the definition of A are not balanced, your loop defining "i" should probably be over len(A[0]).   However, like @ppperry wrote, please show your traceback.

Comment: C is defined only in the inner most for loop's scope. I assume you want to print C after your multiplication is over, so you should define it as an empty matrix before your first loop, just like your other matrices.

Comment: There are several problems here.  One is that C has not been created prior to your attempts to modify its values.  The other is that B looks like it's transposed.  It should be [[3],[5],[6]], i.e. 3x1 rather than 1x3.  As it stands, you will be indexing out of B's bounds inside the loop (since the first index can only be zero).  Finally, the inner loop needs to iterate across columns of A, not rows (i.e. len(A[0]) rather than len(A)).

Comment: Thank you all..I made the corrections and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (Note B is vertical)

```
A = np.array([[1,7,8],[2,7,9],[4,8,8]])
B = np.array([[3],[5],[6]])
C = np.zeros((3,1))

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B[0])):
        for k in range(len(A)):
            C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j]
```

But you also just use np.dot(A,B), which takes advantage of vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the indentation and undefined C. You're probably getting C is not defined error because you simply haven't done so. Define matrix C just like you did with your other matrices and be careful with your indentations, if you define it inside your loops, you can't print it outside either, it would still be undefined outside the scope of your loops.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are explicitly performing the multiplication yourself? This will not scale well. You should use

```
C = np.dot(B,A)
```

or

```
C= B.dot(A)
```

Note also that `numpy` is [row](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/row-major-vs-column-major-row-vectors-vs-column-vectors/) [major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), thus the reversed order of the multiplication.